# .profile not getting executed on chef client

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I have the following recipe on my chef-server:

```
# Insert the environment variables in .profile
execute "set-env-path" do
  command "echo 'export JAVA_HOME=/home/node/jdk1.6.0_45' >> /home/node/.profile && echo 'export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin' >> /home/node/.profile"
end

# Execute .profile
execute "execute .profie" do
  command ". $HOME/.profile"
end
```

When I am running the recipe on the client, the environment variables gets inserted into the .profile but they are not getting set.

```
node@node-virtual-machine:~$ sudo chef-client
[2014-04-07T14:59:57+05:30] INFO: Forking chef instance to converge...
Starting Chef Client, version 11.10.4
[2014-04-07T14:59:57+05:30] INFO: *** Chef 11.10.4 *** 
[2014-04-07T14:59:57+05:30] INFO: Chef-client pid: 24177
[2014-04-07T14:59:57+05:30] INFO: Run List is [recipe[remote_file]]
[2014-04-07T14:59:57+05:30] INFO: Run List expands to [remote_file]
[2014-04-07T14:59:57+05:30] INFO: Starting Chef Run for node-virtual-machine
[2014-04-07T14:59:57+05:30] INFO: Running start handlers
[2014-04-07T14:59:57+05:30] INFO: Start handlers complete.
[2014-04-07T14:59:58+05:30] INFO: HTTP Request Returned 404 Object Not Found: 
resolving cookbooks for run list: ["remote_file"]
[2014-04-07T14:59:58+05:30] INFO: Loading cookbooks [remote_file]
Synchronizing Cookbooks:
[2014-04-07T14:59:58+05:30] INFO: Storing updated cookbooks/remote_file/recipes/default.rb in the cache.
  - remote_file
    Compiling Cookbooks...
Converging 2 resources
Recipe: remote_file::default
  * execute[set-env-path] action run[2014-04-07T14:59:58+05:30] INFO: Processing execute[set-env-path] action run (remote_file::default line 39)
[2014-04-07T14:59:58+05:30] INFO: execute[set-env-path] ran successfully

- execute echo 'export JAVA_HOME=/home/node/jdk1.6.0_45' >> /home/node/.profile && echo 'export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin' >> /home/node/.profile

* execute[set-env-path2] action run[2014-04-07T14:59:58+05:30] INFO: Processing execute[set-env-path2] action run (remote_file::default line 44)
[2014-04-07T14:59:58+05:30] INFO: execute[set-env-path2] ran successfully

- execute . $HOME/.profile

[2014-04-07T14:59:58+05:30] INFO: Chef Run complete in 0.511487679 seconds

Running handlers:
[2014-04-07T14:59:58+05:30] INFO: Running report handlers
Running handlers complete

[2014-04-07T14:59:58+05:30] INFO: Report handlers complete
Chef Client finished, 2/2 resources updated in 1.150640709 seconds
node@node-virtual-machine:~$ echo $JAVA_HOME

node@node-virtual-machine:
```

Why .profile file is not getting executed on the chef client, why my environment variables are not getting set via chef?

Comment: Anyone knows solution for the above?

Answer (score 0):

When Chef runs `execute` resources (including `bash`, `script`, etc), they are executed in a subshell. You are only setting the environment for that subshell, not the Chef Client process. If you need to set the environment variables, you'll need to use a Ruby block and the `ENV` hash:

```rb
ruby_block 'set environment' do
  block do
    ENV['MY_VARIABLE'] = 'MY_VALUE'
  end
end
```

Comment: I used your code, but the environment variables are not getting set permanently. How do I set them permanently on my chef-node from chef-workstation

Comment: You still need to write out an /etc/profile.d or some type of file that is loaded by the shell

Comment: If I write it in /etc/profile.d than I need to reboot the machine for changes to get reflected, I don't want to reboot the system. Is there any other way?

Comment: That's not true - you need to login/logout or just `source /etc/profile`

Comment: In the recepie I entered the command source /etc/profile, I am getting an error that source not found :( I beleive the recepie is not able to detect the source command

Comment: @Prats I'm getting the same error - found a way around this?

Comment: @sethvargo could you add an example on how to `source` the variable to access/rely on it in a later `execute block`? that would be great - couldn't get it to work.

Comment: same here, how do I `source` the `.profile` file permanently?

Comment: I believe you have to source it in each block.